# syncfusion asp.net mvc 6 documentation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, syncfusion

Where can I get syncfusion asp.net mvc 6 documentation like the one that is available for [syncfusion asp.net mvc 5](http://help.syncfusion.com/aspnetmvc/introduction) ?

Comment: If anywhere exists, that will be their site I guess

Comment: @apomene cant find it there the only mvc docs I could find is the one I've linked to in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the below link for preparing your application to use Syncfusion component.

[Getting started - MVC6](http://help.syncfusion.com/aspnetmvc/getting-started#mvc-6-application)

Other features and control initialization are same.

-Madhu

Comment: but for some controls there are tag helpers (found in the mvc 6 samples). Where can I get documentation for those. Thanks.